# Bash: How can I replace a string by new line in osx bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I am googling it a lot. I only want that this line:

```
echo "Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script" | sed -e 's/<newLine>/\n/g'
```

works in my osx terminal and in my bash script. I can't use `sed` for this? Is there another one line solution?

Comment: Does OS X `sed` support this: `sed 's/<newLine>/\o12/g'`? That's the letter "o" rather than a zero. The octal value for a newline is 12. It works on Linux (but so does `\n`).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson not work in my bash :)

Comment: lol, so it not work with my OS X `sed` :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is using sed

```
echo "Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script" | sed 's/<newLine>/\'$'\n/g'
```

And here is a blogpost explaining why - https://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html

Answer (score 4):

Using bash only:

```
STR="Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script"
$ echo ${STR//<newLine>/\\n}
Replace \n it by \n NEWLINE \n in my OSX terminal \n and bash script

$ echo -e ${STR//<newLine>/\\n}
Replace 
 it by 
 NEWLINE 
 in my OSX terminal 
 and bash script
```

A quick explanation here - the syntax is similar to sed's replacement syntax, but you use a double slash (`//`) to indicate replacing all instances of the string. Otherwise, only the first occurrence of the string is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script" |
sed 'G;:a;s/<newLine>\(.*\(.\)\)$/\2\1/;ta;s/.$//' 
Replace 
 it by 
 NEWLINE 
 in my OSX terminal 
 and bash script
```

EDIT: OSX doesn't accept multiple commands see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed)

```
echo "Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script" | 
sed -e 'G' -e ':a' -e 's/<newLine>\(.*\(.\)\)$/\2\1/' -e 'ta' -e 's/.$//' 
Replace 
 it by 
 NEWLINE 
 in my OSX terminal 
 and bash script
```

Yet another way:

```
echo "Replace <newLine> it by <newLine> NEWLINE <newLine> in my OSX terminal <newLine> and bash script" |
sed $'s|<newLine>|\\\n|g' 
Replace 
 it by 
 NEWLINE 
 in my OSX terminal 
 and bash script
```

Comment: @Rodrigo thanks for your reply, it seems that OSX doesn't accept multiple commands as GNU sed. The edit should make it OSX compliant.