# Less ugly way to use sed to simply include a new line?

Tags: sed

There are a lot of guides, handbooks, fast-guides, question/answers about it:  no one are simple and objective...

It is a classical problem, near all text editors crashes with big files XML or HTML "all in one line", so we need to decide what tag will recive the `\n`  and replace all occurences of `<tag` by `\n<tag` ... so simple. Why it is not simple to do by terminal?

The best question/answer about this case not solves: [Bash: How can I replace a string by new line in osx bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10488963/287948)  
Example using that solution: `sed 's/<article/\'$'\n\n<article/g' file.htm`  not works, need some more exotical syntax, so it is not simple as I solicitated in this question.

So, **this quetion is not about "any solution", but about "some simple/elegant solution"**.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(string)/\n$1/' input`

Comment: Hi @choroba, sorry, now including an example of sed command.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell, thanks, is a good solution, but is not `sed`...  I am so sad, 
 perhaps `sed` have no solution ;-)

Comment: `sed` has solutions, but there are many implementations of sed and not all permit the simple solution.  Improving sed was one of the motivations for perl.

Comment: Your solution `sed 's/<article/\'$'\n\n<article/g' file.htm` is half right, a clearer way to view this is to replace `'sed commands'` by `$'sed commands'`. Thus all quoted characters (by which I mean  character preceeded by a back slash) must also be quoted. Which is a long way of saying, try this: `sed $'s/<article/\\n\\n<article/g' file.htm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for you could try something like the following:

`sed 's/<tag>/\n<tag>/g' file.htm`

which is very close to the anwser you linked.
It already looks quite simple to me, it replaces the tag with a new line character and writes the tag again. 
However I don't get the need for this '$' in your case.

Comment: YES!  My first use was `sed '/<tag/\n\n<tag/g' file` that generated an error and my looking for guides... **Why sometimes we need `s/` and sometimes not** with `sed` ?

Comment: `s` stands for substitution. From the sed man page:
       `s/regexp/replacement/
              Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that  portion  matched  with
              replacement. ...`

Comment: @PeterKrauss, please consider to accept the answer if you think it's correct and suits your issue. Thanks

Comment: (it is a new dynamic of Stackoverflow,  it is **not possible to accept** before some little time)  Yes, I see, ... Sorry, was a personal perception... I not understand the **"default sed"**, without `s/`... Now I see, I was using `sed` for  things like `sed -n '/dia/{p;q;}' file1.txt > file2.txt`, so not need the `s/` and do the work like a grep, not like a direct replacer...

Comment: Patterns without the leading `s` are searches to decide which lines to act on. `s///` is an action. so `sed '/foo/ s/bar/bye/g'` means "only replace bar with bye on lines that have a foo." GNU has a great manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Be careful: this solution does not work in all implementations of sed.